# In linux, is there a way I can set dma_handle (virtual io address) alignment condition for dma buffer allocation request?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, riscv

In our SoC design, a device module contains riscv core and we'll allocate a DMA buffer using dma_alloc_coherent and copy the riscv program in that buffer and let the riscv core execute instructions from that buffer.
Of course we'll set the initial program counter with the io virtual address (the returned dma_handle value from the dma_alloc_coherent function) and the iommu of the device will convert the io virtual address to physical address during the instruction and data memory access.

Recently we found a bug and the 64 bit `mtvec` register (trap table base address register) of the riscv core is programmable only for the upper 26 bits. The lower 38 bits are fixed to 0x1c0.  So when a trap happens, it will jump to 0xGGGGGGG0_000001c0 whatever the GGGGGGG part is set with for the mtvec register. If it were not for this bug, we could just allocate a small buffer using dma_alloc_coherent and set the mtvec register with the returned dma_handle and place trap handler code there. But with this bug, we cannot set the mtvec register with the returned dma_handle for the trap handler.
The kernel will allocate a buffer and return the dma_handle which is from a range of virtual address set aside for the device's io virtual address. As I understand, we cannot control the dma_handler value itself but only use the returned value. Is there any way we can tell the kernel when we ask for a dma buffer, like "please return me a dma_handle which has lower 38 bits all zero"?

Comment: Not really. Perhaps you could define a reserved memory region in the device tree for your device to use.

Comment: Regarding my "Not really" comment, there is a DMA pool allocation API that allows the alignment of allocated blocks to be specified, but since the block size is rounded up to a multiple of the alignment size, each allocated block would use up 256 GiB of memory if aligning to a 2^38 boundary, so the allocations are likely to fail!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's badly formatted making my eyes hurt. I wouldn't expect such a bad formatting from experiences SO users...

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks, I've tried a work-around in baremetal simulation and it works ok because I can set any iommu page mapping in baremetal. But it seems there is no dma function that does a mapping for any aribtrary virtual address. So if I use a reserved physical memory region, I cannot still map the physical region to my specific virtual address, can I?

Comment: It looks like somewhere inside the dma_alloc_coherent function, there is this code `*dma_handle = dma_get_device_base(dev, mem) + ((dma_addr_t)pageno << PAGE_SHIFT);` so there is possibility we can tweak linux code for this special case. I'll try when I have time for this.